# Out of browser feature of Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Why and when somebody would take out the Silverlight application out of browser and run? As this is feature provided in Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 2):

When the application is useful enough that you want to use it often and you don't want to depend on a browser or an internet connection, for example.

In Silverlight 4, out of browser applications will make even more sense since they can run with elevated permissions and do things such as accessing the local filesystem or running applications on the client machine: http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/#whatsnew (search *For Trusted applications*)

Comment: But then it would become just like a desktop app? am I right?

Comment: Sort of. You will still have some limitations, mainly due to security reasons and to the fact that Silverlight is a stripped down version of the .NET Framework. But you will run it as a standard desktop application: by selecting it at your start menu, and offline.